# The intersection of pairs of point in two complete quadrangles are in a line.

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, proof-explanation

> If two complete quadrangles are in such way that the intersection of >points between $5$ pairs of correspondent sides are in a line $l$, then >the point which is the $6$ side is also in the line and the four lines >corresponding pairs of correspondent points meet in one point.

My notes have something like this;

Let {A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4} and, {B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4} complete cuadrangles, then we have:

$$A_iA_j\cap B_iB_j = P_{i,j}$$ for all $ i,j \in {1,2,3,4}$ with $ i\neq j$.
Now if All $P_{i,j}$ with one exception are in a line $l$ is clear that that one is also in the line.
To verify that $A_iB_i$ meet in one point for all $i\in {1,2,3,4}$.we can consider the triangles $\triangle A_1A_2A_3$ and $\triangle B_1B_2B_3$, we now that this triangles meet at $P_{i,i}$ for $i \in {1,2,3}$ and each of this points are co-linear so for [Desargues Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues%27s_theorem) $A_1B_1 \cap A_2B_2 \cap A_3B_3$ meet in a point point of perpective. The same can be say to 
$A_iB_i \cap A_jB_j \cap A_kB_k$ for $i,j,k \in {1,2,3,4}$ distinct.

I just don't see why is clear that all $P_{i,j}$ are in a line, could someone explain to me.